# INSERT DATA The database disk image is malformed

Tags: sqlite

We use sqllite to store our data.

Today,when I wanted to insert data in sqllite db,the log showed

> The database disk image is malformed

Answer (score -1):

Im about to try the process as detailed on the link here.
https://www.databasefilerecovery.com/blog/sqlite-error-database-disk-image-is-malformed.html

will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just to confirm, the link provided solutions for that error message. You need to work through them all. Not sure why the downvotes on this, im sure someone can enlighten me.